# Time to live for all messages in activemq queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ttl

I'm new in activemq and jms and I need to set a ttl for all messages in my queue. Is there any possibility to set a ttl of all incoming messages in a queue? I only found an option "*expireMessagesPeriod*" for **policyEntry** tag, which is responsible for checking frequency of expired messages. I understand that I can set the time to live only for a concrete message, not to the whole queue.

Answer (score 6):

ActiveMQ provides a [TimeStampBrokerPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html) that can be used to apply TTL values to message that arrive without a set TTL.  You configure the plugin in your activemq.xml and can use the 'zeroExpirationOverride' value to configure the preferred TTL.

```
<plugins>
  <timeStampingBrokerPlugin/>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply it only on specific queues?

Comment: Not with the default version as far as I know but using it as a template you could always write your own broker plugin to decide which message to modify